# ¿Se puede redireccionar a CreateView y mandar argumentos a la vez?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Muy buenas, tengo la siguiente duda

Si en una vista `DetaiView` de algún modelo A, quiero redireccionar a un vista `CreateView` pero de un medelo B

**¿Cómo puedo pasar argumentos de una vista a otra?**

Por ejemplo, dada las siguientes rutas

```
path('persona/<int:pk>/', PersonaDetailView.as_view(), name='persona-detail'),
```

necesito redireccionar a

```
path('create_paciente/', PacienteCreateView.as_view(), name='create-paciente')
```

**¿Cómo puedo pasar el valores de los algunos campos de Objeto Persona (cualquiera sea el campo que se pueda necesitar) para que el formulario de la vista `PacienteCreateView` muestre información de la persona?**

Por el momento, solo se me ocurre obtener el id del objeto de la vista `DetaiView` a través del método `post`

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    if "id" in request.POST:
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        return redirect('core:create-paciente')
    return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Gracias.

Comment: si tienes un detailview me imagino que estas mostrando datos en tu templates asi que si lo que quieres es simplemente un voton donde te envie a tu url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te puedo sugerir esta solución:

Si tienes tu botón en el path 'persona-detail' que te lleva a la url 'create-paciente' podrías agregar un parámetro get en tu botón, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="create_paciente/?persona_id={{object.pk}}">Crear</a>
```

Así estarías pasando el pk de la persona que estas viendo, posteriormente en tu PacienteCreateView para obtener ese parámetro seria:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    persona_id = self.request.GET.get('persona_id', None) if self.request.method == 'GET' else None
    return super(PacienteCreateView).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Con esto ya obtendrías el pk de la persona, ya dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer con ese id es el método que tendrías que utilizar o sobrescribir (get_context_data, get_initial, etc.)